# Combine global and userspecific information (cache and session)

Tags: c#, .net, session, caching

To make a web-application faster, I'd like to implement caching. There is a class with different lists of elements that I'd like to keep available in cache, because most informations are equal for every user (global). But on the elements are a few user specific information which I have to store and keep fast accessible (session?).

I was thinking about some kind of combination with cache and session but I think that isn't possible? The Information is used on many different places that's why I would like to keep the information as near together as possible. 
Does anybody has a good solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is no built-in way to use them in combination at once, you can write your wrapper class, which fetches the whole information from both parts, for example:

```
class Information
{
  public string UserName { get { return this.GetFromSession("UserName"); } }
  public string WebSiteName { get { return this.GetFromCache("WebSiteName"); } }

  private string GetFromSession(string key)
  { /* get information from session */ }

  private string GetFromCache(string key)
  { /* get information from cache */}
}
```

And then you can just use:

```
Information info = new Information();
Response.Write(info.UserName);
Response.Write(info.WebSiteName);
```

Does this help?

Comment: thanks for your answer Tengiz!
however i'd need it in a deeper level. I've got a list with pages and every page contains multiple (list) elements wich contains several inforamtion about each single element. The position property of the element is the only userspecific thing.. but i dont like to store every element seperatly.. Wouldn't that be necessary with this solution, when i still want to have the possiblity to access the position of the element by element.position? It would be comfortable to access to a session object out of the position propery in the cached element-object..

Comment: Anyway that should be solved by a wrapper class of some kind. I wrote just one example of it, but the implementations differ from case to case.

Comment: i hoped on a possibilty to access out of a chached class to a session variable, but unfortuntely that seems not to be possible.. I'll build somthing like you showed Tengiz, so thanks for your help!